# SimpleXML Parse Format Issue

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

Is there a way I can parse the following:

```
<start_time>2012-01-21 21:00:00</start_time>
```

but only parse the date? Basically I just want to pull 2012-01-21 from it and leave the time out.

I am using this to grab the whole node:

```
echo 'Start Time:'.$events->start_time.'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for this. The answer was way easier than I thought using `substr`

```
echo '<strong>Start Date:</strong>'.substr("$events->start_time", 0, 10).'<br />';
```